# Why won't this URL Rewrite rule fire?

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

Rule is

```
                <rule name="Redirect to new host" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern=".*mycompany\.com/blogs(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://blogs.mycompany.com{C:1}" />
                </rule>
```

The module's built-in pattern tester says that http://subdomain.mycompany.com/blogs/blog1 matches, so it should redirect to http://blogs.mycompany.com/blog1, but nothing happens. Would greatly appreciate help fixing this rule or writing one that does work!

Answer (score 0):

It's work:

```
        <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.*mycompany\.com$" />
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/blogs(.*)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://blogs.mycompany.com{C:1}" />
        </rule>
```

Comment: I am totally willing to buy that, but changing the input to {URL}, the rule still doesn't fire. Even though the built-in pattern tester says it matches (again, like it did before... hmmm, getting the sense that the tester is kind of not worth a damn).